# Scalability : Convert large list of objects into pojo and make api call

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-stream, scalability

Let's say I have a json data of multiple vendors in a large number of categories. I need to make post api calls for top 10 vendors of these hundreds of categories.
How can I do that in a scalable manner?

Each category's post api call has a specific request body. How to map the specific json to each api call's expected request body?

I was thinking something like :

```
json.stream
    .parallel()
    .map((x) -> {
        reqBody = jackson mapper for the request body;
        return reqBody;
    })
    .forEach((body)-> make post call);
```

I thought of polymorphism, but with large number of categories, it's difficult to have a common interface/parent class.
How to make it generic as a reusable library or a utility method?

Comment: Does the mapper need to change the structure of the json-object? Otherwise, you'd be sending the same thing if you just send the json as a string.

Comment: I think it would be best to describe your objects a little more.  If the underlying data structures are different then you may have to go down the polymorphism route, but if they are slightly different you could have a single object that has optional fields, but it's the same object.  So this decision really depends upon your specific situation which wasn't included. Also WHO has this large quantity of data?  It is on the client?  Is it in a storage tier (ie DB)?

Comment: I am getting this data via a POST request in my db from where I fetch it. The reuqest body structure is like { id, description, tariffid, state, channelType, timeStamp}, but the api needs some processing to be done on the desciption, timeStamp and state, can't be directly mapped. Let's say I am able to do it somehow, is there any way to increase throughput?